# How to show merge-base in Magit?

Tags: magit

Is there a way to visually show the merge-base of two branches in Magit?

I think it should be easy to do, there's git merge-base that returns the SHA1 of the commit, so maybe we could mark it in the log screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magit does not visualize the merge-base. (There are commands that use it to do their thing internally though.)

So this is more of a feature request and should be taken to the issue tracker on Github. If you do so then please explain a little more about your use-cases and also how Magit is supposed to know which merge-base to visualize (i.e. if a log shows more than two branches, which two shall it be?).

Comment: @juan I believe this answers your question.